# how to play nginx & rtmp based hls live stream on a remote machine

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I have installed nginx, rtmp and ffmpeg based hls live streaming working on ubuntu machine. I use this command to stream hls

```
sudo ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vprofile high -g 30 -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://localhost/show/stream2
```

when I try to play this stream using VLC using following commands on the same machine it works well.

```
http://myIp:8080/hls/stream2.m3u8
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/hls/stream2.m3u8
```

However when I try to access from remote computer connected to same WIFI, not able to play. VLC gives an error that unable to play the file.

Comment: did you open the ports in ufw?

Comment: Yes. I did. still getting same error after enabling ports and ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem has to be in two places
1. open ports in ufw
2. enable pings in home router